# Is there any risk ing giving a webadmin sudo access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, sudo

I have a normal user on my system who needs to have write access on `httpd.conf`. If I have the following entry in my sudoers file:

```
joe ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/vim /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf
```

Is there any risk in doing this?

Comment: i wouldn't trust a 'normal' user. a syntax error could cause terrible troubles. if you want to grant him these privileges, he probably also needs to restart/reload the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be to change the *group* of that `httpd.conf` file (`chgrp some-group .../httpd.conf`), make the file group writable (`chmod g+w .../httpd.cond`). And make `joe` a member of that group.

But even then, I'm sure `joe` could use that to grant himself more rights as remember `apache` parses its configuration as `root`. It's only later on that it changes to `www-data` or whatever the HTTP user is on your system.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if they open that file with sudo and then do `:!/bin/bash`   ?

I seem to remember you can avoid this in vim (or sudo). But it's worth bearing in mind.

Here you go: [VIM: "sudo vim bad_idea"?](https://superuser.com/questions/23428/vim-sudo-vim-bad-idea)

Basically, you want `rvim`